# Python mock a method when specific argument

Tags: python, mocking

I have a python method like

```
import external_object

from external_lib1 import ExternalClass1
from external_lib2 import Hook

class MyClass(self):

    def my_method(self):
        ExternalClass.get('arg1') #should be mocked and return a specific value with this arg1
        ExternalClass.get('arg2') #should be mocked and return a specific value with this arg2

    def get_hook(self):
        return Hook() # return a mock object with mocked method on it

    def my_method(self):
        object_1 = external_object.instance_type_1('args') # those are two different object instanciate from the same lib.
        object_2 = external_object.instance_type_2('args')

        object_1.method_1('arg') # should return what I want when object_1 mocked
        object_2.method_2 ('arg') # should return what I want when object_2 mocked
```

In my test I would like to realise what I put in comments.

I could manage to do it, but every time it gets really messy.
I use to call flexmock for some stuff  (by example ExternalClass.get('arg1') would be mock with a `flexmock(ExternalClass).should_return('arg').with_args('arg') # etc...`) but I'm tired of using different test libs to mock.

I would like to use only the mock library but I struggle to find a consistent way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I  like to use python's [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) lib. Concretely the `unittest.mock` which is a great lib to customize [side effects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) and [return value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) in unit tested functions.

They can be used as follows:

```
class Some(object):
  """
    You want to test this class
    external_lib is an external component we cannot test
  """
  def __init__(self, external_lib):
    self.lib = external_lib

  def create_index(self, unique_index):
    """
      Create an index.
    """
    try:
      self.lib.create(index=unique_index) # mock this
      return True
    except MyException as e:
      self.logger.error(e.__dict__, color="red")
      return False

class MockLib():
   pass

class TestSome(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.lib = MockLib()
    self.some = Some(self.lib)

  def test_create_index(self):
    # This will test the method returns True if everything went fine

    self.some.create_index = MagicMock(return_value={})
    self.assertTrue(self.some.create_index("test-index"))

  def test_create_index_fail(self):
    # This will test the exception is handled and return False

    self.some.create_index = MagicMock(side_effect=MyException("error create"))
    self.assertFalse(self.some.create_index("test-index"))
```

Put the `TestSome()` class file somewhere like `your-codebase-path/tests` and run:

```
python -m unittest -v
```

I hope it's useful.

Comment: why did you put external_lib as a field of your object ?

Comment: so you plug the real lib when your code runs in production, or the Mocked lib for your unit testing. TDD paradigm.